# Maximum Independent Set of Complete Graph

Tags: graph-theory

> Suppose you have a complete graph with ten nodes (such that there is an edge between all pairs of nodes). What is the maximum independent set of this graph.

I thought the answer was $0$ but I am getting the wrong answer. My reasoning is that in a complete graph there are no independent sets of nodes. Thus the only independent set is the empty set which has size $0$.

Can anyone point me in the right direction about this? I feel as though I am making a simple mistake somewhere but cannot locate it. Have tried googling with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a complete graph the maximum independent set is one. Pick any node and that is the maximum independent set, because by definition of a complete graph it is connected to all other nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't a set containing exactly one node an independent set? This is assuming that your dealing with a *simple* complete graph (no loops).

Answer (score 1):

An independent set of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is a subset $W \subseteq V$ of vertices that satisfies the following property: if $x$ and $y$ are any two distinct vertices in $W$, then $x$ and $y$ are not adjacent.  Observe that this condition is trivially satisfied if $|W|=1$ because in this case $W$ does not have two distinct vertices in the first place.  Hence, every singleton subset $W \subseteq V$ is an independent set (and also a clique) of size $1$.  It follows that the maximum size of an independent set in a complete graph is $1$.